# how can i assign checkbox id to database in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

here i've created a checkbox like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAddress" onclick="checkAddress(this)"/>
function checkAddress(checkbox)
        {
            if (checkbox.checked)

           alert("a");
            }

        }
```

here i have checked the checkbox,if it is checked i want to update the checkbox result to database
so i want to update the checkbox id or value to database..how can i do this??

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of the checkbox using checkbox.id:

```
function checkAddress(checkbox){
    if (checkbox.checked){
      alert(checkbox.id);
   }
}​
```

So you could execute a query like this:

```
function checkAddress(checkbox){
    if (checkbox.checked){
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO checkbox_ids (id) VALUES (\''+checkbox.id+'\')');
        }, errorCallback, successCallback);
   }
}​
```

where errorCallback and successCallback are pre-defined callback functions for your phonegap application.

---

NOTE: In general, it's not best practice to assign callbacks on the `onclick` attributes; rather, you should use more streamlined event listeners.  This way, you can have all of your code in one place.  For example:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAddress" />
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("checkAddress").addEventListener("click", checkAddress, false);

function checkAddress(event){
    checkbox = event.target;
    if (checkbox.checked){
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO checkbox_ids (id) VALUES ('+checkbox.id+')');
        }, errorCallback, successCallback);
   }
}​
```